# How to handle no command-line arguments in D?

Tags: arrays, d

The proper parlance for the `main()` entry point in D is

```
void main(char[][] args)
{

}
```

but how would I know if there aren't any arguments passed, given it's an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> void main(char[][] args)

In modern D, the canonical signature is `void main(string[] args)`, or `void main()` if your program doesn't need arguments.

> but how would I know if there aren't any arguments passed, given it's an array?

Check the array's `.length` property. If `args.length==1`, then no arguments have been passed to the program. (Argument 0 is always the program itself, as in C/C++.)

Comment: I don't see string as a type on dlang.org. Where is this string type, then?

Comment: `string` is defined as `alias string = immutable(char)[]` in `object.d`, which is part of the D runtime and imported implicitly - so it's a standard D type, just defined in the runtime (and not the compiler).

Answer (score 2):

Use `string[]`:

```
void main(string[] args) {
  // Check args.length
}
```

You can also use [std.getopt](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_getopt.html) to do further parsing.

Answer (score 1):

As our friends have already said, use `string[] args`:

```
import std.stdio;

int main(string[] args) {
  if (args.length == 1) {
    writeln("No arguments given. Aborting execution.");
    return 1;
  }
  writeln(args);
  return 42; // answer to everything
}
```

If you have a rather complex case of many parameters, I suggest you take a look at the [std.getopt](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_getopt.html) module.

Here is an example from std.getopt documentation:

```
import std.getopt;

string data = "file.dat";
int length = 24;
bool verbose;
enum Color { no, yes };
Color color;

void main(string[] args) {
  auto helpInformation = getopt(
    args,
    "length",  &length,    // numeric
    "file",    &data,      // string
    "verbose", &verbose,   // flag
    "color", "Information about this color", &color);    // enum
  ...

  if (helpInformation.helpWanted) {
    defaultGetoptPrinter("Some information about the program.",
      helpInformation.options);
  }
}
```